# How is "There are stopped jobs." implemented?

Tags: bash, shell

When I try to exit my shell and I have stopped jobs, it gives me this:

```
$ logout
There are stopped jobs.
$ logout
Connection to x closed.
```

It prevents me from exiting the shell once, warns me, but lets me exit on second attempt.

I want to implement identical behavior for a different scenario:

- on exit, check some condition
- if condition is fulfilled, print warning and prevent exit
- if condition is not fulfilled, or we already prevented an exit, do exit

How can this be done? I've implemented the check and warning trivially using `trap ... EXIT`, but I don't know how to prevent shell exit (once).

*Using bash 4.1.2*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning is implemented as part of `bash` itself.  See [the source code](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/d233b485e83c3a784b803fb894280773f16f2deb/builtins/exit.def#L121) for details.

Comment: You're basically saying, can't be done, short of extending bash... Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

From official [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#What-is-a-shell_003f) of bash

> When an interactive login shell exits or a non-interactive login shell executes the exit builtin command, Bash reads and executes commands from the file ~/.bash_logout, if it exists.

so you can add your script/command in ***~/.bash_logout*** to execute when the shell exits.

With slight modification, the same behavior can be implemented in your program

Comment: I did read your question.  AFAIU, you want to override the "Shell Exit" behavior in your program and you want to put some logic there. Please correct me if i am wrong!

Comment: Quoting myself: *I've implemented the check and warning trivially* -- so you're answering the part that I'm not asking for, and quoting myself again: *but I don't know how to prevent shell exit (once).* -- this part you're missing. It leaves a strong impression that you stopped reading before the end of my question, thus my original comment.